# Error capturing response from TinyURL's shorten method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, short-url

I need to capture the return of the `shorten` method from the `TinyUrl` library. I'm trying to store this return in the `shortUrl` variable and then save it in the database as follows:

```
import TinyUrl from 'tinyurl';

let shortUrl = '';

    TinyUrl.shorten(req.body.url, function (response, error) {
      if (error) console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
      shortUrl = response;
    });

    // Tudo certo para CRIAR o Site
    const { id, hits, url, short_url } = await Site.create({
      hits: 0,
      url: req.body.url,
      short_url: shortUrl,
    });

    return res.json({
      id,
      hits,
      url,
      short_url,
    });
```

When viewing `console.log(response);` the desired return is displayed correctly, but the `shortUrl` variable is not set. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it as follows:

```
const shortUrl = await TinyUrl.shorten(req.body.url);

const { id, hits, url, short_url } = await Site.create({
  hits: 0,
  url: req.body.url,
  short_url: shortUrl,
});
```